# JPA + OrmLIte android: nem todas da entidade são retornadas

Tags: android, hibernate, jpa-2.0

boa noite, eu estou com o seguinte problema.

Estou usando JPA com ORMlite para fazer a persistência no Android. 
Criei uma classe `Produto` e uma `Categoria`, sendo que ambas herdam de uma classe  abstrata `AbstractEntity`.

Ao consultar um produto , ele traz a categoria mas somente com o `id` populado.
A `descrição` e a `imagem` vem como `null`.

Caso eu use a consulta em separado, trazendo somente a lista de categoria, todos os campos são retornados.

Segue o trecho da classe:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 35L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "descricao")
    private String descricao;

    @Column(name = "img")
    private Integer img ;

    public AbstractEntity()
    {

    }
}
```

```
@Entity(name="categoria")
public class Categoria extends AbstractEntity  {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 35L;

    public Categoria()
    {
        //this.setId(new Long(0));
        //this.setDescricao("");
    }
}
```

```
@Entity(name="produto")
public class Produto extends AbstractEntity  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 35L;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Categoria categoria;

    public Produto()
    {
        //this.setId(new Long(0));
        //this.setDescricao("");
        //this.setImg(0);
        ///this.categoria = new Categoria();
    }
}
```

Comment: Como está sua consulta? Como você está avaliando o retorno desta consulta?